# First Java project distinguishing between different instances of class

Tags: java, class

This is my first Java application that I have built, I have successfully created a class for the products, however now I need to declare 4 different instances of products so I can access each individual product in different parts of the code. The code I have at the moment is shown below but I can only seem to acces the last product i have created:

```
   Products = new Products(1,2.50,"Coke",15);

   Products = new Products(2,1.50,"Crisps",5);

   Products = new Products(3,2.00,"Juice",2);

   Products = new Products(4,2.50,"Chocolate",0);

   System.out.println(Products.getProductID()+ " " + Products.getProductName());
```

Is there some way to say 'where product ID is equal to' or assign a individual name to each instance of product? Appolagies if this question has been asked elsewhere I had a look through the related posts but couldn't find anything on this related to Java.
The code below shows my products class:

```
public class Products {

 private int ProductID;
 private double ProductPrice;
 private String ProductName;
 private int ProductStock;

 public Products(int ID, double Price,String PName,int Stock){
  ProductID = ID;
  ProductPrice = Price;
  ProductName = PName;
  ProductStock = Stock;
}

 public void setProductID(int ID){
  ProductID = ID;
 }
 public void setProductPrice(double Price){
  ProductPrice = Price;
 }
 public void setProductName(String PName){
  ProductName = PName;
 }
 public void setProductStock(int Stock){
  ProductStock = Stock;
 }

 public int getProductID(){
  return ProductID;
 }
 public double getProductPrice(){
  return ProductPrice;
 }
 public String getProductName(){
  return ProductName;
 }
 public int getProductStock(){
  return ProductStock;
 }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You should name your variables different if they aren't (you didn't show variable names ...) or make some kind of Collection (ArrayList, List, etc.).
Eg.

```
Products coke = new Products(1,2.50,"Coke",15);
Products crisps = new Products(2,1.50,"Crisps",5);
Products juice = new Products(3,2.00,"Juice",2);
Products chocolate = new Products(4,2.50,"Chocolate",0);

System.out.println(coke.getProductID()+ " " + juice.getProductName());
```

Eg. 2

```
HashMap<Integer, Products> products = new HashMap<Integer, Products>();
products.put(products.size(), coke);
products.put(products.size(), crisps);
products.put(products.size(), juice);
products.put(products.size(), chocolate);

System.out.println(products.get(1).getProductID() + " " + products.get(1).getProductName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Map to lookup by a unique id.

```
Map<Integer, Product> productById = new HashMap<>();

productById.put(1, product1);
productById.put(2, product2);
productById.put(3, product3);
productById.put(4, product4);

// to perform a lookup "where product ID is equal to id"
Product p = productById.get(id);
```